# Error message: LaTeX can't find ieeetrans.sty

Tags: errors, compiling

My code is

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/VTU}
\title{TITLE OF THE THESIS}

\author{by \\ \vspace{2mm}NAME OF CANDIDATE \vspace{5mm}}
\collegeordept{Department Name}
\university{College Name}

\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{A Thesis submitted to \\VISVESVARAYA TECHNOLOGICAL UNIVERSITY \\ Belgaum \\for award of degree of }
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy in -------------}
\degreedate{Year / Year}

\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=50pt

\usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ieeetran}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

\maketitle

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{romanpages}
\include{Certificate/certificate}
\include{Declaration/declaration}
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\include{Dedication/dedication}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\printglossary  
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{romanpages}

\include{Introduction/introduction}
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
\include{Chapter5/chapter5}
\include{Conclusions/conclusions}
\include{Futurework/futurework}

\appendix
\include{Appendix1/appendix1}
\include{Appendix2/appendix2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{References/references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{document}
```

The error says that it cannot find `ieeetran.sty` and the references are not getting displayed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: One quick and dirty fix is to download `ieeetran.sty` from, eg. [here](http://www.cs.utep.edu/interval-comp/apic.95/IEEEtran.sty) and put it in the same folder you've got the .tex file. I think you're on a windows machine (texnic center was the clue!). So, this might be a simple solution.

Comment: Can you try to replace `\usepacage{ieeetran}` with `\usepacage{ieeetrantools}`

Answer (score 2):

`IEEEtran` is a class which is in itself everything you need to write a paper (whether journal or article) in IEEE format.  It includes all the formatting needed for both the paper and the bibliography.  This is declared at the beginning of the document. E.g.:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
```

All the information for writing in IEEE format, along with templates and directions can be found [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran).

Now, if what you want is your *bibliography* on IEEE format, then please visit [this page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex).  Don't forget to read the IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf.

Then it is just a matter of writing:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibligraphy{mybibbliographyfile}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the IEEEtran package. You can do it with the package manager in MikTeX which is probably also already installed.